# Plot gets stuck at 30 on x-axis Xcos

Tags: plot, scilab, x-axis, xcos

So my plot gets stuck at 30 on x-axis. I changed refresh period, so it shows me more of that axis, but there's no plot after 30.

Comment: Change the simulation time !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Simulation/Setup menu item allows to change the simulation time/duration denoted as "Final integration time" (see below) :
[image]